# Where is the error in my SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

My SQL query is

```
ALTER TABLE `USERS` MODIFY `UUID` SERIAL UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

but I keep on getting

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT
NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 1
```

from MySQL (version 5.1). :-(

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.

That's why you don't have to add more attributes to it...

Comment: Just after I posted this question I stumbled upon this fact. Thanks for answering anyway. :-)

Comment: Reference link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html